# SQL Query to change the column format to row for each value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that fetches the data somewhat like  -

#1

```
select 
       assignment_number, 
       ldg_name, 
       effective_start_date, 
       tax_reporting_name, 
       payroll_relationship_number, 
       filing_status, 
       allowance, 
       additional_tax_extra_withold, 
       exemp_fit, 
       exemp_medicare, 
       exemp_wage_accumulation, 
       exemp_unemployment
       
       from
       
       ( SELECT PPRD.payroll_relationship_number, 
               PAAM.assignment_number, 
               PLDG.name 
               LDG_NAME, 
               To_char(PAAM.effective_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                      effective_start_date, 
               (SELECT DISTINCT HOU.name 
                FROM   pay_dir_rep_cards_f PDRCF, 
                       hr_organization_units HOU, 
                       pay_dir_rep_card_usages_f PDRCUF, 
                       pay_rel_groups_dn PRGD1 
                WHERE  PDRCF.dir_card_id = PDCF.dir_card_id 
                       AND HOU.organization_id = PDRCF.tax_unit_id 
                       AND PDRCUF.dir_rep_card_id = PDRCF.dir_rep_card_id 
                       AND PRGD1.relationship_group_id = 
                           PDRCUF.relationship_group_id 
                       AND PDRCF.dir_card_comp_id = PDCCF2.dir_card_comp_id 
                       AND trunc(sysdate) -11 BETWEEN PDRCF.effective_start_date AND 
                                                  PDRCF.effective_end_date 
                       AND trunc(sysdate) -11 BETWEEN 
                           PRGD1.start_date AND PRGD1.end_date) 
                      TAX_REPORTING_NAME, 
               (SELECT DISTINCT Decode (dir_information_char1, '1', 'Single', 
                                                               '2', 'Married', 
                                                               '3', 
                                'Married and withholding at higher single rate'
                                           
                FROM   pay_dir_card_components_f PDCCF3, 
                       pay_dir_comp_details_f PDCDF3 
                WHERE  PDCCF3.dir_card_id = PDCF.dir_card_id 
                       AND PDCCF3.dir_card_comp_id = PDCDF3.dir_card_comp_id 
                       AND PDCDF3.dir_information_category = 
                           'HRX_US_WTH_FEDERAL_INCOME_TAX' 
                       AND trunc(sysdate) -11 BETWEEN PDCDF3.effective_start_date 
                                                  AND 
                                                  PDCDF3.effective_end_date) 
                      FILING_STATUS, 
                      exemp_fit, 
       PDFC.exemp_medicare, 
       PDFC.exemp_wage_accumulation, 
       PDFC.exemp_unemployment, 
       PDFC.exemp_social_security, 
       PDFC.regular_rate, 
       PDFC.regular_amount, 
       PDFC.supplemental_rate, 
       PDFC.supplemental_amt, 
       PDFC.irs_lock_in_date, 
       PDFC.statutory_employee, 
       PDFC.cumulative_taxation, 
       PDFC.primary_address, 
       PDFC.state_disability_calc, 
       PDFC.state_unemp_calc, 
       PDFC.qualifying_dependent, 
       PDFC.other_dependent, 
       PDFC.total_dependent, 
       PDFC.other_income, 
       PDFC.deduction_amount, 
       PDFC.max_federal_allowance ,
       PDFC.allowance, 
       PDFC.additional_tax_extra_withold
       from 
       per_all_assignments_m paam,
       per_all_payroll_relationship PPRD,
       per_legislative_table PLDG,
       Per_cards PDCF,
       Per_components PDFC
       WHERE PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER = PPRD.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER
       AND PPRD.LEGAL_UNIT = PLDG.LEGAL_UNIT
       AND PDCF.dir_card_id = PDFC.dir_card_id
       AND PDFC.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID
       AND trunc(sysdate) -11 BETWEEN PAAM.effective_start_date 
                                                  AND 
                                                  PAAM.effective_end_date)
```

The above query is giving me the correct output in the format-

```
 assignment_number  ldg_name effective_start_date tax_reporting_name payroll_relationship_number filing_status  allowance additional_tax_extra_withold  exemp_fit  exemp_medicare  exemp_wage_accumulation  exemp_unemployment      
10                  US          02-Aug-2020         Ontario                 10-1                    Single       1000       10                          Y           N
```

I need these columns in the format(Columns into rows) -

```
ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER       ValueDefinitionName
10                      filing_status       
10                      allowance
10                      additional_tax_extra_withold
10                      exemp_fit
10                      exemp_medicare
```

i.e. the column names which ever is not null for an assignment_number.

Also,  in the format ,

```
ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER       ValueDefinitionName                             Value1
10                      filing_status                                   Single
10                      allowance                                       1000
10                      additional_tax_extra_withold                    10      
10                      exemp_fit                                       Y
10                      exemp_medicare                                  N
```

Since   exemp_wage_accumulation and exemp_unemployment is null it should not be included.

Is there any way possible to achieve using my first query#1?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use unpivot for this...

Here is a way to do this. I replaced the large query you got as a temp block with the appropriate data types--> data. You would need to replace the query that i have in the "data" block with the large query you got and also make sure that the datatypes for all of the columns you got is consistent (in this case all of the non-varchar columns are type casted to varchar)

After that you can use unpivot as follows

```
with data
  as (select  assignment_number
             ,ldg_name                    
             ,to_char(effective_start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy') as effective_start_date
             ,tax_reporting_name          
             ,payroll_relationship_number 
             ,filing_status               
             ,to_char(allowance)  as allowance
             ,to_char(additional_tax_extra_withold) as additional_tax_extra_withold
             ,exemp_fit                   
             ,exemp_medicare              
             ,exemp_wage_accumulation     
             ,exemp_unemployment 
      from t 
      ) 
select *
 from data
unpivot (value1 for valuedefinitions in (
                      ldg_name                    
                      ,effective_start_date
                      ,tax_reporting_name          
                      ,payroll_relationship_number 
                      ,filing_status               
                      ,allowance 
                      ,additional_tax_extra_withold
                      ,exemp_fit                   
                      ,exemp_medicare              
                      ,exemp_wage_accumulation     
                      ,exemp_unemployment          
                   ) 
        )


+-------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
| ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER |       VALUEDEFINITIONS       |   VALUE1    |
+-------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
|                10 | LDG_NAME                     | US          |
|                10 | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE         | 02-aug-2020 |
|                10 | TAX_REPORTING_NAME           | Ontario     |
|                10 | PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_NUMBER  | 10-1        |
|                10 | FILING_STATUS                | Single      |
|                10 | ALLOWANCE                    | 1000        |
|                10 | ADDITIONAL_TAX_EXTRA_WITHOLD | 10          |
|                10 | EXEMP_FIT                    | Y           |
|                10 | EXEMP_MEDICARE               | N           |
+-------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
```

Here is a db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9d211abbede82e276464333018a70731

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method but it will work only if all columns except assignment number are of same type i.e. varchar or integer. You can have your main query as CTE.

Note: This is not a complete working query but just a hint to get you started.

```
with table1 as (...You existing query...)
SELECT ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER, "FILING_STATUS" AS VALUEDefinationname, filing_status as value1 from table1 where filing_status is not null
union
SELECT ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER, "allowance", allowance from table1 where allowance is not null
```